# what replaces register_modifier in Smarty 3

Tags: php, smarty, template-engine

I'm looking at upgrading to Smarty 3 from 2 and have a small number of modifiers registered using

```
register_modifier($ModifierName, $FunctionName)
```

I can't find the place in the documentation where it indicates what I should change these to, I've tried.

```
$Smarty->Register->Modifier(
```

but get an error.  Can someone point me to the documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out its been moved to

```
registerPlugin()
```

http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.register.plugin.tpl